# How to import an iPhone Project from XCode 3.1.3 - SDK 3.0 to XCode 3.2.3 - SDK 4.0.1

Tags: iphone, xcode, sdk

I have an annoying situation here: I have updated my mac from Tiger to Snow Leopard, and my XCode has also been upgraded from from XCode 3.1.3 - SDK 3.0 to XCode 3.2.3 - SDK 4.0.1. The problem is: I can't run my projects anymore. The SDK 3.0 can not be found (and I have already read in Internet that there is no SDK 3.0 available to XCode 3.2) ans ALL the frameworks I had in my Project can also be not recognized. How can I please fix this? I want to be able to run my project with the new XCode and with the new SDK.

I would be very, very glad to hear any suggestions. Thanks a lot in advance for answering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the base SDK of your project to 4.0 and the deployment target to 3.0. This will allow you to still deploy on 3.0 devices. In XCode, highlight your project and hit get info. Then click on the build tab. It should say "Base SDK" near the top. Select iPhone Device 4.0 from the list. Then in the search bar type "deploy". Near the bottom you should see iPhone OS Deployment Target. Select iPhone OS 3.0 from this list. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

Is this the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658035/iphone-app-made-using-xcode-3-2-3-does-not-run-on-3-1-3-os/2902149#2902149)?

With iOS4, Apple has changed the way that they do the SDK.  You will compile ALL programs against the iOS4 or 3.2 (iPad) SDK, but you set the Deployment Target in your project settings to choose the minimum OS version you want to support.